# Can SimpleCV read out multiple USB camera simultaneous in Windows 7?

Tags: simplecv

I've been using OpenCV to read out camera output and process the frames. I am on Windows 7, and it turns out that OpenCV cannot simultaneously read multiple USB cameras in Windows. Does anybody have an experience with SimpleCV in Windows 7 in this direction? Is it capable of displaying output of multiple USB cameras in Windows 7 simultaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the core developers for SimpleCV and I'm guessing if OpenCV can't do it than it won't work.  We have pygame as a graceful fallback on linux and mac but a camera interface doesn't exist to it on windows sadly.  I have still yet to find a good open source solution to just viewing a webcam on windows either.